# XPath works in the Chrome console, but it does not work in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Here is the screenshot of the HTML structure for the page I am trying to scrape.

[image]

You can see that there is a `<table>` element with `class="waffle"`. When I use the XPath specification `//table[@class='waffle']` in the Chrome console, it works as expected:

[image]

However, when I use the same path on Selenium, it doesn't work.

```py
  container_xpath = "//table[@class='waffle']"
  # wait
  try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    container = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, container_xpath)))
    print('container found')
  except Exception as e:
    print('container not found')
    raise PageDidNotLoadError
  return
```

The Python script prints "container not found".

What is wrong with Selenium?

Comment: can you share page url?

Comment: this is the page URL https://www.cardrush-pokemon.jp/page/38
please note that it takes ~10 secs to load the table in question

Comment: switch to the iframe and then retrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe style="border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: red; width: 1000px; height: 200000px;" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQT3Q9qDbZUpnP3_WH2I5qw8O-U_PqXVhhoIzH2o-tSzeDND9FTuoGKbZiNHTbrzTgKAUA2_SvXFh_2/pubhtml?gid=159569114&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false&amp;gid=0&amp;range=A:F" width="320" height="240"></iframe>    

<iframe id="pageswitcher-content" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQT3Q9qDbZUpnP3_WH2I5qw8O-U_PqXVhhoIzH2o-tSzeDND9FTuoGKbZiNHTbrzTgKAUA2_SvXFh_2/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&amp;gid=159569114&amp;range=A:F" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

You need to switch to the inner iframe after switching to the outer one.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#pageswitcher-content")))
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s a common practice to hide the elements under a nested iframe. You need to switch to the outer iframe first and then to the inner frame.

The below code should work for you:

```python
# Switch to outer iframe
oframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(oframe)

# Switch to nested frame
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe#pageswitcher-content')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Get the container
container = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, container_xpath)))
```

To get the same in a table form, you can do:

```python
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html(container.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

|  | Unnamed: 0 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4 | Unnamed: 5 | Unnamed: 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | カード名 | 仕様 | レア | 型番 | タイプ | 状態A |
| 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | 3 | 【スペシャルアート(TAG TEAM GX)】 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | 4 | フシギバナ＆ツタージャGX | SA | SR | 066/064 | 草 | 3300 |
| 5 | 5 | セレビィ＆フシギバナGX | SA | SR | 097/095 | 草 | 3500 |
| 6 | 6 | モクロー＆アローラナッシーGX | SA | SR | 056/054 | 草 | 3300 |
| 7 | 7 | フェローチェ＆マッシブーンGX | SA | SR | 056/054 | 草 | 2300 |
| 8 | 8 | レシラム＆リザードンGX | SA | SR | 097/095 | 炎 | 20000 |
| 9 | 9 | リザードン＆テールナーGX | SA | SR | 068/064 | 炎 | 6000 |
| 10 | 10 | カメックス＆ポッチャマGX | SA | SR | 070/064 | 水 | 5000 |
| 11 | 11 | コイキング＆ホエルオーGX | SA | SR | 099/095 | 水 | 5500 |
| 12 | 12 | ヤドン＆コダックGX | SA | SR | 096/094 | 水 | 4000 |
| 13 | 13 | ピカチュウ＆ゼクロムGX | SA | SR | 101/095 | 雷 | 30000 |
| 14 | 14 | ライチュウ＆アローラライチュウGX | SA | SR | 057/054 | 雷 | 5500 |